# Can't add Mapbox and MapboxNavigation SDK

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, mapbox, mapbox-ios

In order to implement Mapbox SDK, according to official docs (https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/overview/#install-the-maps-sdk,
https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/navigation/overview/), adding *Mapbox-iOS-SDK* and *MapboxNavigation*  through Cocoapods, always get error, shown bellow.
I thought this is related to the usage of *sourcery* or *SwiftGen* which are the parts of project or something else, but this happened on new, clean project also, where inserting SDKs was the first step.

- Cleaned derived data for few times,
- remove from Podfile versioning for that SDK (*pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'*, '~> 6.0.0'  as *pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'* )
- even when SDK is added through CocoaPods, can't find frameworks to add into *Link Binary With Libraries*
- even it says *Copy Bundle Resources* to be checked, couldn't find what to expect there

Note:

- Also tried: successfully added Mapbox and MapboxMobileEvents directly into project, but as I found MapboxNavigation SDK could be implemented only through CocoaPods or Carthage, so I'm stuck here.

I would really appreciate for someone's help, who already have faced this problem.

```
 Multiple commands produce '/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mbNavigationExample-ctztmwiegsuqkigkucoydhnnoaxc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/mbNavigationExample.app/Assets.car':
1) Target 'mbNavigationExample' (project 'mbNavigationExample') has compile command with input '/Users/x/Desktop/mbNavigationExample/mbNavigationExample/Assets.xcassets'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'mbNavigationExample' (project 'mbNavigationExample'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

[image]

Comment: At the very least show your entire pod file.

Comment: @Magnas thx for update 